# Call a JavaScript function with parameters when click on href

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to come up with code that would create an href tag with a JavaScript functions which gets parameters. Parameters are a string and an object converted into a json string.
My attempt was something like this:

```
return '<a style="text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer" target="_blank"' +
                   ' href="javascript:goToStateNewWindow(\'trending\', \'' + JSON.stringify(params) + '\')">' + value + '</a>';
```

The error was:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

In Inspect window it looked like this:

```
<a style="text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer" target="_blank" href="javascript:goToStateNewWindow('trending', '{" projectid":2313,"alarmsonly":"true"}')"="">test</a>
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what was the unexpected token?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Sorry. But everything. Here's how you should create the element, e.g. in a function.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var t = document.createTextNode(value);
a.appendChild(t);
a.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
a.style.cursor = 'pointer';
a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
document.body.appendChild(a); // or any other element you want the a to appear in
a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  goToStateNewWindow('trending', params);
});
```

Note that you could also style the element with css before...

Comment: But +1 for "Sorry. But everything." :D

Comment: @Gothdo Thank you, changed it!

Comment: for your constructive critic... +1 too :-) -.-.- @Gothdo

Comment: No, there is a reason for a return statement. I need to return a complete string.

Comment: Hm, then there might be something wrong in the code you didn't show. @Mark. What would make sense is to return the element (maybe) so that you can read values of it - but there are still better ways to do that. Please show the rest of your code

Comment: When I move mouse over the link I see javascript:goToStateNewWindow('trending', '{  That's all. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it shouldn't be an `<a>` element, but a `<button>`. You can use CSS to make it look like `<a>` if you want.

Secondly, you should rather create en element using `document.createElement()`, add the attributes and specify a click event listener using the `addEventListener()` method.

```
const element = document.createElement('button')
element.setAttribute('type', 'button')
element.setAttribute('style', 'text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;')
element.setAttribute('target', '_blank')
element.addEventListener('click', event => goToStateNewWindow('trending', params))
element.innerHTML = value

return element.outerHTML
```

Comment: See my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

I want to explain why it doesn't work. It's because in your html you have `href="javascript:...` when you call `JSON.stringify(params)` it returns `{"projectid":2313,"alarmsonly":true}` then the javascript parser stops at the first double quote after `href="` (`{"`) and the rest (`projectid":2313,"alarmsonly":true}...`) become invalid javascript.

I made a function who replace double quotes with single quotes and that worked. May not work if the object have a string value with double quotes.

```js
function goToStateNewWindow(route, body){
  console.log('Route: ', route);
  console.log('Params: ', body);
}

function doublequotetosingle(obj) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/"/g, "'");;
}

function test(params, value) {
  return '<a style="text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer" target="_blank"' +
    ' href="javascript:goToStateNewWindow(\'trending\',' + doublequotetosingle(params) + ')">' + value + '</a>';

}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', test({ projectid: 2313, alarmsonly: true }, 'test'));
```